# Why does Field Calculator say failure during processing, check geoprocessing results window for details?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, field-calculator

I am using the Field Calculator and keep receiving the following error: 'There was a failure during processing, check the geoprocessing results window for details'. I am not very tech-savvy but I have tried a few simple fixes and still have had no luck. It's only a simple division equation so i'm confused.

My equation is [Sum_NO_OF_] / [KM2AREA]

Comment: could you be trying to divide by zero? Verify that KM2AREA is not zero for all records

Comment: Thanks Stephen. There is one field in which KM2AREA is 0 (row 1). Do you know how I can calculate without including this value?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 3):

To ensure that you don't calculate an illegal division by zero, first ensure that all values of KM2AREA are not zero.

You can do this using the [Select By Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000) functionality (presuming you're using ArcMap - other GIS's will have a similar function.

Then ensure that the Field Calculator is set to the default of only using the selected values.